# Real-time line charting with React-Native

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, linechart, react-native-svg

I'm new to drawing a graph with react-native. The problem is, I can read the data sent with Ble as a value on the screen, but I'm having trouble making real-time graphs. There must be a mistake somewhere. I tried many different methods.

The code below is my screen code.

```
const disconnectDevice = useCallback(async () => {
    navigation.goBack();
    const isDeviceConnected = await device.isConnected();
    if (isDeviceConnected) {
      await device.cancelConnection();
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
  }, [device, navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDeviceInformations = async () => {
      // connect to the device
      const connectedDevice = await device.connect();
      
      setIsConnected(true);

   
      // discover all device services and characteristics
      const allServicesAndCharacteristics = await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
      // get the services only
      const discoveredServices = await allServicesAndCharacteristics.services();
    

      setServices(discoveredServices);
  
     
       PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Permission Localisation Bluetooth',
          message: 'Requirement for Bluetooth',
          buttonNeutral: 'Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
          
        }
      );     
      };  
    getDeviceInformations();

    device.onDisconnected(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    });

    // give a callback to the useEffect to disconnect the device when we will leave the device screen
    return () => {
      disconnectDevice();
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    };

    
  }, [device, disconnectDevice, navigation]);
   
 

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={disconnectDevice}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:"SairaExtraCondensed-Thin",textAlign:"center",fontSize:15,color:"white"}}>Antrenmanı Sonlandır</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.header} >
          <Text>{`Name : ${device.name}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Is connected : ${isConnected}`}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
        <>
        {services &&
          services.map((service) => {
            return(
          <>
          
          <ServiceCard service={service} />
          <LineChart
              style={{ height: 200 }}
              gridMin={0}
              gridMax={300}
              data={[service]}
              svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }}
              contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}>
            </LineChart></>
            )
          })}
        </>
          </View>
      </View>
      <View>

    

      </View>
     
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

The service component, where the values ​​were decoded last, is as follows;

```
type ServiceCardProps = {
  service: Service;
  
};


const ServiceCard = ({ service }: ServiceCardProps) => {
  const [descriptors, setDescriptors] = useState<Descriptor[]>([]);
  const [characteristics, setCharacteristics] = useState<Characteristic[]>([]);
  const [areCharacteristicsVisible, setAreCharacteristicsVisible] = useState(
    false,
    
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getCharacteristics = async () => {
      const newCharacteristics = await service.characteristics();
      setCharacteristics(newCharacteristics);
      newCharacteristics.forEach(async (characteristic) => {
        const newDescriptors = await characteristic.descriptors();
        setDescriptors((prev) => [...new Set([...prev, ...newDescriptors])]);
      });
    };

    getCharacteristics();
  }, [service]);
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          setAreCharacteristicsVisible((prev) => !prev);
        }}>
        <Text>{`UUID : ${service.uuid}`}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {areCharacteristicsVisible &&
        characteristics &&
        characteristics.map((char) => (
          <CharacteristicCard key={char.id} char={char} />
        ))}
      {descriptors &&
        descriptors.map((descriptor) => (
          <DescriptorCard key={descriptor.id} descriptor={descriptor} />
        ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Data is being decoded with Ble. Then it is displayed as a value on the screen via the latest service map. I want to see the graph on the screen in real time like in this code. What error could be below?

Nothing appears on the screen. I only see values.

Thanks